# Can you make the cursor move smoothly when typing in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there any setting or package in sublime text 3 that makes the cursor move smoothly when typing like in [monkeytype.com](https://www.monkeytype.com)
That just makes me wanna type forever.

Comment: I see what you mean, [monkeytype.com](https://www.monkeytype.com) certainly has the smoothest caret I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no setting that exposes this sort of cursor movement through the file, while typing or otherwise.

It's also not possible via a package, since the rendering of the display is done in the core, and isn't something that can be modified by plugin code.